# Show $\alpha^m = \varepsilon$ working with permutation groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Show that $\alpha^m = \varepsilon$ using $\alpha^\ell (a_i) = a_{(i+\ell) \bmod{m}}$ where $\alpha = (a_0 a_1 \dots a_{m-1}) \in S_n$ a permutation group.

I've been working on this problem but can't seem to get anywhere. Any direction is always appreciated

Comment: what is $\varepsilon$? Identity element?

Comment: Yes $\varepsilon$ is identity, sorry!

Comment: Take the formula after "using" and stick in $m$ and notice that $(i+m)\mod m$ is just $i$, so you have $\alpha^m(a_i)=a_i$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the group of permutations of lenght n is finite there exists n and p for which $a^n = a^p $ with n > p. By multiplying with $a^{-p}$ we have $a^{n-p} = e$.